# Vuejs Cannot assign value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wrote this code by Vue js but I got a problem.

When I called plus() method, the browser langs and refreshes not stop.

```
<div id="app">
<div v-for="(v,i) in list">
    {{v}}
    {{plus(v)}}
</div>
</div>


<script src="./public/js/vue.js"></script>
<script>
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        tmp: 0
    },
    methods: {
        plus(v) {
            this.tmp += v
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

[Bowser Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8KHs.png)

Comment: calling a method inside template will make an infinite loop, what do you want to achieve by calling that method?

Comment: I have a list of items and I want to show the total price at end of the table @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: Nope, It won't, Calling a method inside template is completely fine. You can check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-5kbumu).

Comment: You are in render method rendering the list of item using some state value. Render method is triggered whenever any state changes. So You might have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

Comment: Change `data` to a function, `data() { return {list:....}}`

Answer (score 0):

Calling a method inside template will make an infinite rendering, in order to get the sum of your item just define a computed property that does that for you based on the items :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(v,i) in list">
    {{v}}
  </div>
  <b>
    {{total}}
  </b>
</div>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      tmp: 0
    },
    computed: {
      total() {
        return this.list.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          return  acc += +curr;
        }, 0)
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```